# Passing []net.Conn to io.MultiWriter

Tags: go, slice

I have many of `net.Conn` and i want to implement multi writer. so i can send data to every available `net.Conn`.

My current approach is using `io.MultiWriter`.

```golang
func route(conn, dst []net.Conn) {
    targets := io.MultiWriter(dst[0], dst[1])

    _, err := io.Copy(targets, conn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

but the problem is, i must specify every `net.Conn` index in `io.MultiWriter` and it will be a problem, because the slice size is dynamic.

when i try another approach by pass the `[]net.Conn` to `io.MultiWriter`, like code below

```golang
func route(conn, dst []net.Conn) {
    targets := io.MultiWriter(dst...)

    _, err := io.Copy(targets, conn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

there is an error "cannot use mirrors (variable of type []net.Conn) as []io.Writer value in argument to io.MultiWriter"

Is there proper way to handle this case? so i can pass the `net.Conn` slice to `io.MultiWriter`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`io.MultiWriter()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#MultiWriter) has a param of type `...io.Writer`, so you may only pass a slice of type `[]io.Writer`.

So first create a slice of the proper type, copy the `net.Conn` values to it, then pass it like this:

```
ws := make([]io.Writer, len(dst))
for i, c := range dst {
    ws[i] = c
}

targets := io.MultiWriter(ws...)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i need to `Close` the `net.Conn`, if using this approach i can't to implement `.Close` on every `net.Conn` i have.

Comment: @nothinux You said nothing about closing in the question. Also, I don't understand what's the problem with closing. You still have the `dst` slice holding the `net.Conn` values, you _can_ close those.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention about closing the `net.Conn`. i didn't think i can close it in `dst`, i only think i must close the `net.Conn` after make that as `io.Writer`. Thank you for your help @icza